# Bash with cat for automatic merging pair of files

Tags: bash, cat

I have a list of files starting with L- and a folder called L with inside files with the same name, for instance L-some and L/L-some.

For each file L- I want to merge append its content into L/L-. I have tried with this, but is not working.

```
for f in L-*; do "cat L/$f $f > L/$f"; done
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You are basically rewriting each file with that >. Use >> to append as heemayl showed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do:

```
for f in L-*; do cat "$f" >>L/"$f"; done
```

This gets each `L-` file in the current directory (`L-*`) and append (`>>`) its content (`cat "$f"`) in the file with same name in `L` directory (`cat "$f" >>L/"$f"`).